# how to display a message box for a user in Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to display a message box to show some message in Java, and the box should have three buttons that the user can press such that the program can get value when user presses the button.

Comment: what do you mean by a "jump box"?

Comment: mean like JOptionPane , jump a box when program running

Comment: i remember i used some class and can add button name before,but i forget class name

Comment: *"..like JOptionPane"* Use a **`JOptionPane`.**

Answer (score 3):

If you use Java Swing then take a look at

[JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
//Custom button text
Object[] options = {"Yes, please",
                "No, thanks",
                "No eggs, no ham!"};
int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
"Would you like some green eggs to go "
+ "with that ham?",
"A Silly Question",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null,
options,
options[2]);
```

Please refer to oracle documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)